# Why is the command not gettng the input with pipe in bash?

Tags: bash, pipe, stdin

I am trying to do something simple in bash but I cannot get it to work. I have defined the variable:

```
 export devcluster2="10.122.22.22"
```

in my .bashrc. When I type:

`echo $devcluster2` I get as expected:

```
10.122.22.22
```

now I want to do:

```
echo '$devcluster2' | ssh
```

but I get

```
usage: ssh [-1246AaCfgKkMNnqsTtVvXxYy] [-b bind_address] [-c cipher_spec]
       [-D [bind_address:]port] [-e escape_char] [-F configfile]
       [-I pkcs11] [-i identity_file]
       [-L [bind_address:]port:host:hostport]
       [-l login_name] [-m mac_spec] [-O ctl_cmd] [-o option] [-p port]
       [-R [bind_address:]port:host:hostport] [-S ctl_path]
       [-W host:port] [-w local_tun[:remote_tun]]
       [user@]hostname [command]
```

I want to understand why the `ssh` doesn't get the output of echo as an input? and how can I get it to work?

Comment: Single quotes don't expand variables and `ssh` doesn't take the host to connect to from standard input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To ssh to a host, you use:

```
ssh 10.122.22.22
```

If you want to ssh to a host in a variable, you therefore use:

```
ssh "$devcluster2"
```

Meanwhile, `echo text | command` is like running `command` and then typing in "text". If you to run `ssh` by itself and wait for an opportunity to enter text, it fails just like it does in your script:

```
$ ssh
usage: ssh [-1246AaCfgKkMNnqsTtVvXxYy] [-b bind_address] [-c cipher_spec]
           [-D [bind_address:]port] [-E log_file] [-e escape_char]
           [-F configfile] [-I pkcs11] [-i identity_file]
...
```